# Sed to replace single quotation mark

Tags: sed

I'm going crazy on a simple thing. I have written the following line that is amazingly working:

```
name=$(echo $name | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/^ //' | sed 's/ $//' | sed "s/'/\\\'/")
```

I'm trying to reduce sed to only one command instead of four, and I wrote the following line that doesn't work, and I cannot manage to make it work:

```
name=$(echo $name | sed 's/"//g; s/^ //; s/ $//; s/\'/\\\'/g')
```

I get:

```
sed: 1: "s/"//g; s/^ //; s/ $//; ...": unterminated substitute in regular expression
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't see the syntax error, I've tried to rewrite it many times, the line with 4 sed works, but this where I try to put all in one sed it doesn't.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Use a good editor. Even coloring on stackoverflow here is hinting you.

Comment: You should double-quote variable references (e.g. `echo "$name"` instead of just `echo $name`) to prevent weird parsing before the value even gets to `sed`. See ["I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) (but note that this doesn't apply *just* to `echo`; it applies almost everywhere). [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting common mistakes like this.

Comment: Good suggestion Gordon, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot embed a single quote in a single-quoted string, no matter now many escapes you use: [3.1.2.2 Single Quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes)

You can use sed's `-e` option to chain the commands and give you the most quoting flexibility:

```sh
sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/^ //' -e 's/ $//' -e "s/'/\\\'/"
# or
sed -e 's/"//g; s/^ //; s/ $//' -e "s/'/\\\'/"
```

Comment: Thank you Glenn, I firstly missed the option -e, then I had no idea I could not use single quotation mark inside a SQM, then the escapes were completely useless, now it's all clear, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^ |"| $//g;s/'\''/\\&/g' file
```

Use alternation to remove a space at the start/end of a line or double quote.

Replace a single quote by an escaped single quote.

It is not possible to have solution with a single substitution as the RHS of the substitution is different in one of the four cases i.e. first 3 cases remove strings whereas the fourth case adds one.

If, however you intend to remove the single quote, use:

```
sed -E 's/^ |["'\'']| $//g' file
```

Comment: @EdMorton Oops!

Answer (score 1):

You can also abut quotes anywhere to need to switch them.  Just be careful of interpolation, per usual with double-quotes:

Instead of

```
name=$(echo $name | sed 's/"//g; s/^ //; s/ $//; s/\'/\\\'/g')
```

do

```
$ name=$(echo $name | sed 's/"//g; s/^ //; s/ $//;'" s/\'/\\\'/g")
```

although I think what you want may actually be

```
$ name=$(echo $name | sed 's/"//g; s/^ //; s/ $//;'" s/'//g")
```

Adjacent quotes are just like any other adjacent characters.  With no intervening whitespace, they constitute a continuing string.

Comment: I've never seen the $ with a space before a variable, I will need to read about it. Thank you very much James I appreciated your help.

Comment: @Renato the `$` at the start of the line is just a very common prompt as set in `PS1`, it has nothing to do with the variable or any part of the command.

Comment: Sorry James, I thought was part of a script, it's obviously the bash user symbol, sorry again.

Comment: `echo $name` is really bad. Try `a='  -n  a  b  c  '; echo $a` (with multi spaces) and you get `a b c` (with single spaces). Better is `echo "$name"`.  Even better is `sed ... <<< "$name"` without echo.

Comment: @Wiimm, I seen no reason in SO answers to supply fully generalized code unless the question regards generalization or portability.  Perfect accuracy comes at the cost of clarity; a simple answer that gets to the point is better than a fully general one that obscures it.  (I wouldn't recommend `<<<`, though, because it's specific to bash.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the third method of bash quoting: `$'...'`. Here C like escapes are possible. So your sed command can be:

```
sed $'s/"//g; s/^ //; s/ $//; s/\'/\\\'/g'
```

But if you want, that the input `a'b` becomes `a\'b`, then use

```
sed $'s/"//g; s/^ //; s/ $//; s/\'/\\\\\'/g'
```

Analyzing `\\\\\'`: bash reads it as `\\'`. And sed reads it as `\'`.

Comment: I will need to read about ```$'...'```,  since I've never seen it before. Thank you Wiimm I appreciated the suggestion!